# SQlite using statement gives Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' error on another computer

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, using, using-statement

This is the code that I wrote for database connection:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{                       
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString)) 
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database Opened");

                ushort[] writeData = new ushort[10];
                writeData = parseList(byteList);

                if (writeData != errorBytes)
                {
                    writeToDb(con, writeData);
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Bytes returned! BROKEN DATA!!!");
                }

                //con.Close();
            }

            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Can't open the database!");
            }
        }
    }`
```

When I run the program on the computer that I wrote the code it works properly and opens the database. However when I run my program in another computer code doesn't go into `using` statement and gives the exception `SQLite.Interop.dll` not found. I added the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` to my project's references. Also I have this dll file in the other computer. Do I need to add anything to the other computer to make this program work properly?

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work_? You get any exception or error message in other computer? What do you mean it doesn't go into using statement?

Comment: can you try catch all this block in order to have information about that code?

Comment: It just skips the part which starts with using statement. There is no exception. But now I noticed that there is no try and catch statement to catch the exception. I will add the try and catch statement and write the error info here. Thanks!

Comment: The part which starts with `using` is the whole method...are you sure `OnTimedEvent` is being called?

Comment: Yes it works when I write something to console before using statement it writes. But if try to write something in using statement it doesn't write anything to console.

Comment: I edited the question about the exception information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that the problem was about SQLite dlls. When I installed the System.Data.SQLite library from NuGet Package Manager and set the platform target as x86 problem resolved. Although platform target was x86 before I asked this question but re-installing the library from NuGet Package Manager solved my problem. Before that I was using the dlls I downloaded from the http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki as reference to my project.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the connectionString, the location of the SQLite file,.. Maybe you are trying to create it somewhere where your program is not allowed to write on the other computer. Try to run your app as administrator if there is a difference. The only thing that came on my mind is that it crashes at the moment of creating the connection and therefore it is not going into the using statement.